# CSS and selectors - why do mass groupings not work for things like h1, h2 etc?

Tags: html, css

This is from an older document of mine:

```css
body {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #333;
}
header {
background-color: #C71585;
border: 3px solid;
border-radius: 3px 6px;
color: #FFFFFF;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 20px;
width: 400px;
}

div.content {
border: 2px solid;
width: 600px;
}

header h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
color: #FFFFFF;
}


h1, h2, h3, h4 {
color: #333;
```

```html
<header>
<h1>DAILY NEWS</h1>
<h2>London Edition</h2>
<h3>South East News inside</h3>
</header>
<div class="content">
<h1>Headline today</h1>
<h2>By John Doe</h2>
<h3>Politics Correspondent</h3>
<p>In today's news, the Government pledges to spend £4.5million on a regeneration plan.</p>
</div>
```

In this, the header text is white only for the first one.

For the second example, I've had to make individual header H1, header h2 in CSS:

```css
body {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #333;
}
header {
background-color: #C71585;
border: 3px solid;
border-radius: 3px 6px;
color: #FFFFFF;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 20px;
width: 400px;
}

div.content {
border: 2px solid;
width: 600px;
}

header h1, header h2, header h3, header h4, header h5 {
color: #FFFFFF;
}


h1, h2, h3, h4 {
color: #333;
```

```html
<header>
<h1>DAILY NEWS</h1>
<h2>London Edition</h2>
<h3>South East News inside</h3>
</header>
<div class="content">
<h1>Headline today</h1>
<h2>By John Doe</h2>
<h3>Politics Correspondent</h3>
<p>In today's news, the Government pledges to spend £4.5million on a regeneration plan.</p>
</div>
```

Why is it that you have to declare all the header at once using CSS selectors as header h1, header h2 etc.?

I also tried header > h1 etc. which does the same sort of thing:

```css
body {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #333;
}
header {
background-color: #C71585;
border: 3px solid;
border-radius: 3px 6px;
color: #FFFFFF;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 20px;
width: 400px;
}

div.content {
border: 2px solid;
width: 600px;
}

header > h1, header > h2, header > h3 {
color: #FFFFFF;
}


h1, h2, h3, h4 {
color: #333;
```

```html
<header>
<h1>DAILY NEWS</h1>
<h2>London Edition</h2>
<h3>South East News inside</h3>
</header>
<div class="content">
<h1>Headline today</h1>
<h2>By John Doe</h2>
<h3>Politics Correspondent</h3>
<p>In today's news, the Government pledges to spend £4.5million on a regeneration plan.</p>
</div>
```

In general, for selectors, what is best practise:

selector element - e.g. **header h1**

selector and parent e.g **header > h1**

for a HTML5 document?

Comment: You overwrote your own css, `h1, h2, h3, h4 { color: #333;` the h1 works because it has a higher specificity

Comment: "Best practice" is just opinions of more than one person, or the opinion of the person in charge. Use what you need that makes sense and has adequate performance characteristics for your needs.

Comment: As far as "why", you'd have to ask the people who made the decision regarding selectors years ago. Probably because back then, there wasn't a need to style things like that. Or maybe people just had a higher tolerance for typing things out. Or copying and pasting and changing one character on each line...

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of [`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is), grouping is possible.

> The :is() CSS pseudo-class function takes a selector list as its argument, and selects any element that can be selected by one of the selectors in that list. This is useful for writing large selectors in a more compact form.

```css
header :is(h1, h2, h3) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<header>
<h1>DAILY NEWS</h1>
<h2>London Edition</h2>
<h3>South East News inside</h3>
</header>

<h1>DAILY NEWS</h1>
<h2>London Edition</h2>
<h3>South East News inside</h3>
```

Comment: While this works but the root issue is the OP overwrote his own css so the more specific rule applies. Also check support before using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is

Comment: No, the OP wants to know why `header h1, h2, h3, h4, h5` doesn't work....that's the root question here.

Comment: Sure, but this answer doesn't answer "why". It answers "how can I make it work".

Comment: @Paulie_D that's exactly what I mean, the why is never explained, the root issue is because the css was not specific enough which is why nothing worked beyond h1

Answer (score 1):

You state, "In this, the header text is white only for the first one". That is correct as your only targeting `<h1>` elements that are descendants of `<header>` with the [`Descendant combinator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator). The other selectors in the list of comma separated selectors ie `h2, h3, h4, h5` are applying but being overridden by the `h1, h2, h3, h4 { color: #333 }` right beneath it. The `header h1` style persists as it has higher specificity.

A comma-separated list of selectors represents the union of all elements selected by each of the individual selectors in the list.

```css
body {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #333;
}
header {
background-color: #C71585;
border: 3px solid;
border-radius: 3px 6px;
color: #FFFFFF;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 20px;
width: 400px;
}

div.content {
border: 2px solid;
width: 600px;
}

header h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
color: #FFFFFF;
}


h1, h2, h3, h4 {
color: #333;
```

```html
<header>
<h1>DAILY NEWS</h1>
<h2>London Edition</h2>
<h3>South East News inside</h3>
</header>
<div class="content">
<h1>Headline today</h1>
<h2>By John Doe</h2>
<h3>Politics Correspondent</h3>
<p>In today's news, the Government pledges to spend £4.5million on a regeneration plan.</p>
</div>
```

For the second example,

> Why is it that you have to declare all the header at once using CSS selectors as header h1, header h2 etc.?

It's not necessarily required to use the descendant combinator to apply styles, but it does have to do with which styles have higher specificity. This essentially means how browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied.

Here is a few examples of specificity scenarios:

- Inline css ( html `<style>` attribute ) overrides css rules in style tag and css file
- A more specific selector takes precedence over a less specific one
- Rules that appear later in the code override earlier rules if both have the same specificity.
- A css rule with `!important always` takes precedence.

```css
body {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #333;
}
header {
background-color: #C71585;
border: 3px solid;
border-radius: 3px 6px;
color: #FFFFFF;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 20px;
width: 400px;
}

div.content {
border: 2px solid;
width: 600px;
}

header h1, header h2, header h3, header h4, header h5 {
color: #FFFFFF;
}


h1, h2, h3, h4 {
color: #333;
}
```

```html
<header>
<h1>DAILY NEWS</h1>
<h2>London Edition</h2>
<h3>South East News inside</h3>
</header>
<div class="content">
<h1>Headline today</h1>
<h2>By John Doe</h2>
<h3>Politics Correspondent</h3>
<p>In today's news, the Government pledges to spend £4.5million on a regeneration plan.</p>
</div>
```

In conclusion, from my understanding there really isn't a "best" way to apply styles with certain selectors or combinators. You just choose which selector combinations or combinators to use based on the specific styling need, while keeping [`specificity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) in mind.